# Clear Splash Browser Cache

Tags: php, python, splash-js-render

I'm trying to visualize a website speed analysis. As a headless browser I use Splash 3.2 ... unfortunately I have problems getting a correct har file.

The first request looks good, after the second request I get only requests that were not cached.

I tried to empty the cache with a post request to the _gc endpoint, unfortunately without success.

My curl requests:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8050/render.har?url=' . esc_url( $url ) .'&response_body=1&wait=5&timeout=10';
    $cache_url = 'http://localhost:8050/_gc';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $cache_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"cached_args_removed=1");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_reset($curl);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

the result of _gc request:

```
{"cached_args_removed": 0, "pyobjects_collected": 1269, "status": "ok"}
```

Afterwards I tried to start Splash with --disable-browser-caches to get a correct output, but Splash does not cache anything and therefore makes many requests to the same files, if they occur several times.

Is there another way to flush the browser cache before rendering, or should I prefer to use another headless browser (recommendation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tobias

You mentioned you're using splash version 3.2

I'm the author of [PR 821](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/pull/821) which introduced **--disable-browser-caches** , and according to [the changelog](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#33-2019-02-06) , this feature landed in splash version 3.3.
So please upgrade to splash version 3.3 and you should be able to use that feature.